# What happened to apoc.load.csv

Tags: neo4j, apoc, load.csv

I am using neo4j

Neo4j Browser version: 5.3.0

Neo4j Server version: 5.3.0 (community)

Neo4j Browser Changelog

Build number: 207

Build date: 11/21/2022

I installed the corresponding version of apoc 'https://github.com/neo4j/apoc/releases/download/5.3.0/apoc-5.3.0-core.jar'

The apoc.load.csv is missing:

``` There is no procedure with the name ``apoc.load.csv`` registered for this database instance. ```

When I run
`SHOW PROCEDURES yield name, description, signature`

It should've been between these two lines:

```
"apoc.load.arrow.stream"    "Imports nodes and relationships from the provided arrow byte array."   "apoc.load.arrow.stream(source :: BYTEARRAY?, config = {} :: MAP?) :: (value :: MAP?)"
"apoc.load.json"    "Imports JSON file as a stream of values if the given JSON file is an array.
If the given JSON file is a map, this procedure imports a single value instead."
```

The version 5 documentation has it listed [here](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/5/import/load-csv/)

Comment: Downrev'ing to which version fixes it for you?

Comment: The documentation you have linked is of apoc extended package not of apoc core. You will need to setup apoc extended as well, in your database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Neo4j 5 APOC has been split into two separate distributions: [APOC Core](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/5/) and [APOC Extended](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/5/). `apoc.load.csv` has been moved to APOC Extended so you'll want to be sure you have that distribution installed.

This page has more information and installation instructions for APOC Extended: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/#_availability_installation